# Does aluminium (III) react with copper?

Tags: electrochemistry

We all know know that Aluminium react with cupric producing Copper and Aluminium (III), but does Aluminium (III) react with Copper?

Comment: Do you knot that is better not to mix aluminum and copper wires? http://homeguides.sfgate.com/problems-aluminum-copper-wire-electricity-86313.html